# Express, Node Error - connectDB is not a Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to express and tyring to connect to mongoAtlas via Express and start the server. I am facing an error where I have no clue why is it coming. Can someone help me out?

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db);
    console.log('MongoDB Connected...')
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

module.export = connectDB;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

// Connect database
connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running...'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; 

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change

```
module.export = connectDB;
```

to

```
module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: is there anything like `module.export` or is it always `module.exports` (even when there is only 1 item to export)?

Comment: always `module.exports`, unless you get into ES6 where you could just do `export default connectDB`